# basic java gui program

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane, windowlistener

I need help writing a GUI application that:

• When an attempt is made to close the window, the user should be asked via a
dialog to confirm that they indeed wish to terminate the application, via
supplying a y (yes) or n (no) indication. If ‘y’ is entered then the application
should immediately terminate, if ‘n’ is entered it should stay visible. 
i almost have this down, but I cant get the window to stay visible after clicking no on the JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog();

• When the user minimises the window by clicking the appropriate icon, a message
dialog should appear saying “Minimising the window”

• When the user restores the window, a message dialog should
appear saying “Restoring the window”.
This would be of great help to me.

Comment: Have you gone to the tutorials in particular the ones covering [ComponentListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) and [WindowListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html)? If so, when you've tried doing what they recommended, what doesn't work? Can you show us your code?

Comment: You are asking to much questions. Try to isolate them and be specific as possible.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of the question: You can add a `WindowListener` to your application's top level `JFrame` containing the following:

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        doExit(); // Will not return if user clicks yes.
        super.windowClosing(e);
    }
});
```

... and then implement `doExit()` as follows:

```
private void doExit() {
    int yesNo = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Are you sure you wish to exit?", "Confirm", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    if (yesNo == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

In addition you need to add the following method call when initialising your application:

```
mainAppFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```